# Can a bean be autowired in an abstract bean?

Tags: spring

I have a abstract bean "home", a child bean "homechild" and a bean "my" to be injected in the parent. I tried to autowire the "my" bean in the parent. But it does not happen. Is this because autowiring in a abstract bean is not possible?

```
<bean id="home" class="my.test.own.spring_book_ch3.HomeImpl"
      autowire="byType" abstract="true"/>
<bean id="homechld" parent="home"/>
<bean id="my" class="my.test.own.spring_book_ch3.MyImpl"/>
```

When I explicit inject, it works.

```
<bean id="home" class="my.test.own.spring_book_ch3.HomeImpl"
      autowire="byType" abstract="true">
  <property name="my" ref="my"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is **No**, abstract parent bean cannot use autowire for injection.

From spring's [reference document](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-child-bean-definitions) the child bean dictates the autowire mode

> A child bean definition inherits scope, constructor argument values, property values, and method overrides from the parent, with the option to add new values. Any scope, initialization method, destroy method, and/or static factory method settings that you specify will override the corresponding parent settings.
>
> The remaining settings are always taken from the child definition: *depends on, **autowire mode**, dependency check, singleton, lazy init*.

Also the container ignores the abstract beans from instantiation thus no question of autowiring any dependencies.

> `ApplicationContext` pre-instantiates all singletons by default. Therefore, it is important (*at least for singleton beans*) that if you have a (parent) bean definition which you intend to use only as a template, and this definition specifies a class, you must make sure to set the abstract attribute to `true`, otherwise the application context will actually (*attempt to*) pre-instantiate the abstract bean.